# Strange isomorphism: $R/(A + B) \cong (R/B)/\bar{A}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

$R$ is a ring and $A, B$ are ideals of $R.$

I was playing around with some stuff and I was wondering if $R/(A + B) \cong (R/B)/\bar{A}.$ for $\bar{A}$ being the image of $A$ under $R \rightarrow R/B.$ I'm pretty sure I have a proof for it. I will post a 'proof' of it as an answer if the isomorphism is correct. I simply don't know if it is correct because I have never seen this before. Or...is it just plain wrong?

Comment: Are those modules, vector spaces, groups, rings, algebras...?? What is $\;\overline A\;$  in this respect, anyway?! Not all here can read minds...

Comment: Perhaps you should specify what kind of objects $R, A, B$ are. The $+$ notation suggests that they are abelian groups?

Comment: It's correct since $\overline A=A\cdot R/B=(A+B)/B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a consequence of the second isomoprhism theorem (on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Third_isomorphism_theorem_3) is anyway refered as the third): $B \leq A+B \leq R$ implies that
$$
 R/(A+B) \cong (R/B)/((A+B)/B)
$$
Where is not hard to prove that $(A+B)/B$ is the image of $A$ through thr map $\pi : R \to R / B$

Answer (score 2):

We have a map from $R \rightarrow (R/B)/\bar{A}$ which is a homomorphism as this is the composition of the natural maps $R \rightarrow R/B$ and $R/B \rightarrow (R/B)/\bar{A}.$ It is also surjective as it is the composition of surjective maps. It is not difficult to see that the kernel is $A + B.$ However, @JayTuma's answer seems to be a more direct approach using the second isomorphism theorem.

Comment: nice thing here is that you actually proved the second ismorphism theorem :)